# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(KeyEvent) in KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, awt, keylistener

I am trying to make a small game where you have to dodge rectangles as an oval and I encountered this problem.

```
Dodge is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(KeyEvent) in KeyListener
```

I have scoured the internet to try to find an answer but I cannot find a fix to it.

```
package dodge;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Dodge extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

private int x = 5, y = 5;

public Dodge(){
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    //setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);

    repaint();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dodge game = new Dodge();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Dodge the Rectangles");
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.  For custom painting in a `JPanel`, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)`.  Using either method, we should immediately call the appropriate `super` method.  Calling `repaint()` from either will cause an infinite loop.  Instead use a Swing based `Timer` to control animation.

Comment: As an aside.  You mentioned you were new to GUI coding.  That example seems to be based on some very sub-standard ways of doing things.  I highly recommend you abandon whatever resource currently being used to learn, and instead use Oracle's own [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: thank you, but do you know of any youtube videos that will help walk me through the problems that i may have along the way.

Comment: No.  I have a YouTube channel myself (not coding related), but don't have the bandwidth allowance or internet speed to actually *watch* YouTube videos.  I don't truly feel that people can learn coding from videos anyway..

Comment: Take a momement to have a read through [How to Write Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to see a solution for your current problem, but as Andrew said, Key Bindings are a better solution. Try and avoid YouTube videos in the future ;)

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out, you need to write or inherit every method that is required by any interface you implement. As a convenience implementing interfaces, an interface may have associated with it a class that provides default implementations for some or all of its methods.

In the case of KeyListener, the convenience class is java.awt.event.KeyAdapter. It provides empty methods. If you extend it, you only need to directly implement the method you want.

To find the convenience class for an interface, scan its "All Known Implementing Classes" list.

Comment: Extending a `KeyAdapter` here would be impossible since OP's class already extends `JPanel`. Perhaps another alternative would be to create a separate class that extends `KeyAdapter`?

Comment: @PakkuDon Good point. I separate my listeners from my components by writing the listener as an inner class. I think it makes the code cleaner, as well as allowing use of adapters.

Answer (score 2):

You have to Override a method `keyReleased(KeyEvent)` as you are implementing an interface (`KeyListener`).

**Rule:** You have to override all the methods defined in an interface that you are implementing if your class is not abstract.

Add this code in your `Dodge` class and give a try.

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
  //code.
}
```

As `KeyListener` has two more methods.

1. **`keyTyped(KeyEvent e)`**
2. **`keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`**

You need to override them as well if you want your class to keep implementing `KeyListener`.

Comment: how would i override them. Sry im new to this.

Comment: how could i override them whenever i do @Override nothing happens

Comment: *"..nothing happens.."*  That is the ideal.  The thing is, it issues a compiler error if the method does **not** override a defined method.  For example, if you wrote `@Override public void keyReleaseddddd(KeyEvent ke)` the code compilation would fail, alerting you to the fact that the `d` key got stuck.  Give it a try to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `implements KeyListener`, which means "I am going to implement the methods defined in the KeyListener interface", but you haven't actually done so.

If you want your game to be controllable by the keyboard, you can still use KeyListener (although it's kind of an old technique). But if you do, you will have to implement its methods.

If you don't, and this was a mistake, just remove the `implements KeyListener`.

Comment: what would a new technique be because i am only doing this as practice because i want to make a small portion of pokemon on a java engine where you can walk around on a map and encounter wild pokemon and such?

Comment: see Andrew Thompson's comment above for that.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, it looks like a big problem but it isn't. Just add the following line to your code

```
@Override public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e ){}
```

Comment: Please elaborate *why* and *how* this changes the issue.